# delete method with string arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a method that will delete a CD (CD include artist name, album title, and track titles).. there are 5 CDs and I want to delete on of them... this is what the method should do :
**void delete()** will 1) ask the user for an artist and title, then attempt to find a CD with 
matching artist and title, 2) display the CD if found, or tell the user it was not found, and 3) 
if found, ask the user to confirm deletion (this needs keyboard input), deleting the CD
entry if the user confirms.

and this is my code:

```
public void delete() {
    Scanner deleteInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which artist you would like to delete? ");
    System.out.println("Enter artist name and title to be deleted:");
    String artist = deleteInput.nextLine();
    String title = deleteInput.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i <= CDlist.length - 1; i++) {

        if ((CDlist[i].getArtist().equals(artist))
                && (CDlist[i].getTitle().equals(title))) {
            System.out.println("Found: " + CDlist[i].getArtist() + " "
                    + CDlist[i].getTitle());
            if (CDlist[i] == null) {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like to delete it? Yes 0 No 1");                
            if (deleteInput.nextInt() == 1) {
                CDlist[i] = null;
                cdnum--;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("CD not found in the list.");
        }
    }
```

my problem is that when I type the correct Artist and Title to be removed I'm getting output as CD not found ( but it should say found and then removes it) how do I fix this please?

Comment: This looks like Java so I have tagged it as such. Feel free to fix it if I am incorrect. You'll get more responses if you tag things appropriately.

Comment: `getArtist()` does return a String?

Comment: DEBUG: See the value in `artist` and `CDlist[i].getArtist()` and see why the dont match. Try case insensitive match. And also to add your null check is in wrong place.

Comment: yes getArtist returns artist which is a string

Comment: You're going to get CDList.length -1 or -0 amount of "errors" because you have all your logic inside the for loop. Use the for loop just to see if the CD is in there or not. Then write error messages / confirmation message outside the loop.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao should I use compare to?

Comment: @Sanchit can you explain more please?

Comment: @user2168344 No just convert them both to lowercase strings and compare if you want a case insensitive compare.

Comment: @Danny Can't I leave it the same way it was type? For example I have a CD called Micheal Jackson Thriller... when I use the delete method I get asked what is the name of the CD, I input Micheal Jackson Thriller, and it should find it and  remove it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant. Also you have an extra `{` in your first `if` right after the for loop starts. I hope that isn't causing an issue.

I have added the ignore case part based on some comments.

```
public void delete() {
    Scanner deleteInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which artist you would like to delete? ");
    System.out.println("Enter artist name and title to be deleted:");
    String artist = deleteInput.nextLine();
    String title = deleteInput.nextLine();

    boolean found = false;
    int idx = -1;

    System.err.println("DEBUG: Input Data");
    System.err.println("Artist Name: "+artist+" Length of String: "+artist.length());
    System.err.println("Title: "+artist+" Length of String: "+title.length());
    System.err.println();

    for (int i = 0; i <= CDlist.length - 1; i++) {

        if (CDlist[i]!=null) {
            System.err.println("DEBUG: Checking Index "+i);
            System.err.println("Artist Name: "+CDlist[i].getArtist()+" Length of String: "+CDlist[i].getArtist().length() + " Matches: "+CDlist[i].getArtist().equalsIgnoreCase(artist));
            System.err.println("Title: "+CDlist[i].getTitle()+" Length of String: "+CDlist[i].getTitle().length() + " Matches: "+CDlist[i].getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title));
            System.err.println();
        }

        if (CDlist[i]!=null && CDlist[i].getArtist().equalsIgnoreCase(artist) && CDlist[i].getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(title)) {
            System.out.println("Found: " + CDlist[i].getArtist() + " " + CDlist[i].getTitle());
            found = true;
            idx = i;
                    break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to delete it? Yes 0 No 1");                
        if (Integer.parseInt(deleteInput.nextLine()) == 1) {
            CDlist[idx] = null;
            //I am assuming cdnum is a variable of the class that can be accessed.
            cdnum--;
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("CD not found in the list.");
    }
}
```

Note: You need not put CDlist[i] in an if statement on its own you can just merge into the other statement. This can be done because java looks at things left-> right and so it'll check for null before trying to do anything. You can put it on its own but you'll need to put it BEFORE your first if statement.

Comment: But [i] System.out.println("Would you like to delete it? Yes 0 No 1");                
        if (deleteInput.nextInt() == 1) {
            CDlist[i] = null;
            cdnum--;
        } can't be found, this the error I get

Comment: Alright I test the code and I still got CD not found in the list in my output... and the CD was not removed.. and it didn't ask me if i wanted to delete the CD.. it should as ask me for Yes and NO

Comment: Okay I'm putting in a debug version that should help you solve all your problems on your own. sec.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a newbie with computer programming... why did you make idx = -1 ?

Comment: It can be anything. Its just a placeholder for the index where we find the matching CD. It is only used when found = true. We need idx because i does not exist outside of the loop.

Comment: I see... Well I did a run now... it only asked me if want to delete Yes 0 No 1 I input 0 but it didn't remove it and it didn't tell me it was found... and I'm pretty sure I typed the artist name and the title correctly

Comment: I had accidentally removed the System.out that tells you that it was found. 0 means don't delete. 1 means delete. Thats what your code says.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but please bare wit me... can you give me the final edit it (good) code? I'm tottaly lost, I have been working on this assignment for HOURS...

Comment: alright it told me it found it.. GOOD.. HOWEVER it didn't remove the CD

Comment: so any idea on why it didn't get deleted ?

Comment: Instead of `deleteInput.nextInt()` write `Integer.parseInt(deleteInput.nextLine())`. That could be the only problem left.

Comment: Woah!! thanks... but I don't know a lot about debug, i'm in intro java class :/

Comment: You cant use nextInt(), next() etc after doing a nextLine(). They dont teach you that in java class. But now you'll know forever!

Comment: Alright i'm going to test it and see how it goes... hopefully it will work

Comment: Well its the stuff stored in the CD then. My debug code should have alerted you.